# Ansible jinja2 template from JSON format provided as extra-vars

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook, jinja, jinja2

I have this jinja2 template:

```
# {{ ansible_managed }}

{% for vhost in nginx_vhosts %}
{%- if vhost.name == item.name -%}

# redirect www to non-www
server {
    listen {{ nginx_port }};
    listen [::]:{{ nginx_port }};
    port_in_redirect off;

    server_name www.{{ vhost.name }};
    return 301 http://{{ vhost.name }}$request_uri;
}
{%- endif -%}
{%- endfor -%}
```

An ansible role with an yaml file **vhosts.ym**l containing definitions like this:

```
nginx_vhosts:
      - name: "test1.com"
        repo: "git1"
        branch: master
        state: present
      - name: "test2.com"
        repo: "git2"
        branch: master
        state: present
...
      - name: "test101.com"
        repo: "git101"
        branch: master
        state: present
```

A task inside **playbook.yml**:

```
- name: "Generate nginx vhost configuration file"
  template:
    src: templates/nginx-vhost-template.j2
    dest: "{{ nginx_vhosts_dir }}/{{ item.name }}.conf"
    owner: "{{ nginx_user }}"
    group: "{{ nginx_group }}"
    mode: 0640
  with_items:
    - "{{ nginx_vhosts }}"
  when:
    - item.state == 'present'
  notify:
    - nginx-restart
```

I ran a taks like:

```
ansible-playbook -l web1 playbook.yml --tags=nginx-vhost-config
```

which is working fine, it will create from template a nginx vhost configuration file on the remote server as domain1.com.conf and so on for all the found definitions.

Assuming that in the vhosts.yml file I have test1.com up to test100.com, I'll add let's say test101.com and I want to run the tasks strictly for that test101.com and not for all previous hosts. So I tried something like this:

```
ansible-playbook -l web1 playbook.yml --tags=nginx-vhost-config -e "{ 'nginx_vhosts': { 'name': 'test101.com', 'state': 'present', 'repo': 'git101', 'branch': 'master' }}"
```

The issue with this is that it results in an error when trying to replace values from the jinja2 template.

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleUnicode object' has no attribute 'name'
```

I've also tried using **loop** instead of **with_items** but no luck.

I understand that when using the extra-vars, the provided content is in JSON format but I was not able to find a different way to pass the content from vhosts.yml as extra vars for one single entry. Is there any way to make this functional?

Is there a better approach maybe?

Comment: One minor note: what you are passing in is YAML, not JSON. It looks a lot like JSON because it's flow-style YAML, but is easily distinguished because JSON doesn't allow single quotes to be used the way they are here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing in an object/dictionary but your code is expecting a list. You need to either wrap it in a list when you pass it in, or account for the different possible structures when you consume it.

You should first reduce the number of places that reference `nginx_vhosts` by using the current loop item directly in your template:

```
# {{ ansible_managed }}

# redirect www to non-www
server {
    listen {{ nginx_port }};
    listen [::]:{{ nginx_port }};
    port_in_redirect off;

    server_name www.{{ item.name }};
    return 301 http://{{ item.name }}$request_uri;
}
```

You can then modify the structure you pass in slightly:

```
"{ 'nginx_vhosts': [{ 'name': 'test101.com', 'state': 'present', 'repo': 'git101', 'branch': 'master' }]}"
```

Or modify your loop slightly:

```
- name: "Generate nginx vhost configuration file"
  template:
    src: templates/nginx-vhost-template.j2
    dest: "{{ nginx_vhosts_dir }}/{{ item.name }}.conf"
    owner: "{{ nginx_user }}"
    group: "{{ nginx_group }}"
    mode: "0640"
  loop: "{{ [ nginx_vhosts ] | flatten }}"
  when:
    - item.state == 'present'
  notify:
    - nginx-restart
```

Comment: It makes sense now. It works like a charm! Thank you!